# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_3/Conv2D}}

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

For this CNN model:

```
# Construct model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```

I am getting the ValueError message:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_3/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_3/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,84,64], [2,2,64,128].
```

I tried putting `padding='same'` in the last convolution layer like:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1), padding='same')
```

as suggested [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079115/valueerror-negative-dimension-size-caused-by-subtracting-2-from-1-for-max-pool) but it still did not work.

Why is this error occurring and how to fix it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because the dimensions of your input are too small. With you current setup, the `num_rows` and `num_columns` cannot have values lower than 9. To fix the issue, one thing you could do is to increase the values of the variables (and thus your input size) `num_rows` and `num_columns` to at least `9`.

There is one more thing you could do. There are certain layers in your network that decrease the dimensionality of the data as it propagates through your network. These are your `Conv2D` layers, and your first `MaxPooling2D` layer. You can preserve the size of your input by making changes to these layers. For the `Conv2D` layer, you can use the `padding="same"` argument when creating your layer like so:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', padding='same'))
```

For the `MaxPooling2D` layer, you can use the `pool_size=1` argument when creating your layer, as you are already using with all of your `MaxPooling2D` layers but the first.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  I am focusing on your second answer.  Is there any advantages of using the `model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))` in the first layer as opposed to adding the `padding='same'` to all the `model.add(Conv2D(filters=XX,...` layers?  Thanks!

Comment: It's better to add `padding='same'` to the `Conv2D` layers than to use `pool_size=1` in the `MaxPooling2D` layers. The main benefit of using `MaxPooling2D` is the extraction of more prominent features in the intermediate feature maps produced by other layers. Having a `pool_size` of `1` undoes that benefit. On the other hand, having `padding='same'` in `Conv2D` layers allows you to better propagate the information near the edges through your network.

Comment: With that being said, should I then change the ‘pool_size=2’ in the other layers and have ‘padding=same’ on all the layers?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Change `pool_size` to `2` in `MaxPooling2D` layers, and have `padding="same"` in your `Conv2D` layers. Also, please mark the answer as accepted if your query has been fully answered.