# Loading data to CNN form OpenCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I loaded frames from video files with OpenCV to an array and i used sklearn to split the data into `X_train` and `X_test`.

My `X_train.shape` is `(363, 1, 40, 40, 15)`, currently I'm working with 4 classes, and the model I'm using to learn from this data is coded bellow:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(32, (3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 40, 40, 15), data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv3D(256, (2,2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(256, (2,2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

I'm getting this error when I try to load the model:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'conv3d_44/convolution' (op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes: [?,25,1,1,256], [2,2,2,256,256].
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been discussed several times on StackOverflow: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48796061/712995) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089027/712995). According to your convolutional and pooling layer parameters, the tensor is downsampled after each `Conv3D` and `MaxPooling3D`. Here's how the model looks like just before it breaks:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, 32, 38, 38, 13)    896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 32, 19, 19, 13)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)            (None, 30, 17, 17, 64)    22528     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPooling3 (None, 30, 8, 8, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)            (None, 28, 6, 6, 128)     221312    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)            (None, 26, 4, 4, 128)     442496    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPooling3 (None, 26, 2, 2, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)            (None, 25, 1, 1, 256)     262400
```

The tensor `(None, 25, 1, 1, 256)` can't be downsampled further, hence the 
error.

The solution is to tweak `Conv3D` parameters: either use `padding='same'` (in which case the tensor shape is preserved after the convolutions and is halved only after pooling layers) or reduce the filter sizes from `3` to `2`.

Example:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 40, 40, 15), data_format='channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(256, (2,2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(256, (2,2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```